# Amount of money the department Production spent last month on salaries in mySql queries

Tags: mysql

which query could get that going for me please? having a hard time!I am trying to write as a query in mysql using a sample employee database.

Comment: We don't have your table name. We don't have your table structure. We don't even have at least a piece of your code showing how you are trying to do this. I suggest you to provide these things of your question will be down voted for most users who see it.

Comment: I suggest you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you post what you are currently trying to do. We won't do your homework for you.

Some reading you might want to do:

- http://forums.mysql.com/
- [SQL- Add up Values in a Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9334686/sql-add-up-values-in-a-column)
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm
- [Good MySQL primer / learning resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578900/good-mysql-primer-learning-resources)

The statement would be in the ballpark of:

```
select sum(Production) as MyColumnSum from departments
```